# What's the rationale of not preserving case (by default) in configparser?

Tags: python, configparser

If I want to preserve key names in a config file, I must add `configparser.optionxform = str`. I was surprised by this ([**configparser**](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser)) behaviour, expecting case-preservation to be the default (if not the only) option.

Does this make sense to you? What's the rationale behind this decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only affects the case of the option names, the case of values is always preserved.  It can be argued, whether this is a sane choice, but the choice has been made and must now be followed in order to maintain compatibility with old sources.

I don't see any big problem, since you obviously found a workaround for yourself.  You might alternatively try configobj.  It is powerful, has a much more convenient and reasonable API and does by default preserve case of options.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is "That's what Windows' config files do".